# How to match two curves in time in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab and I face a problem. I have two datasets, let's say (t,y1) and (t,y2). Those are measurements of the same experiment with two different methods. There is a time delay between those two. y1 and y2 values should correspond in time. Do you have any idea how can I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: My time vectors are same in length, I thought crosscorr is not the right choice. or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the time points are equal for both `y1` and `y2`, [`xcorr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html?refresh=true) should tell you when the alignment is maximal.

```
[r,lags] = xcorr(y1,y2);
[~,idx]  = max(r);
y2_shift = lags(idx);  %// amount of shift needed to correct y2
```